# Devise migration on existing model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm migrating from Authlogic to Devise.

UPDATED:

The migration of devise tries to re-create the table users, so i changed as you can see below the create_table to change_table and drop table at the end to remove what i add

The problem is when I run rake i get an error .

This is the error I get when running rake.

```
==  DeviseCreateUsers: migrating ==============================================
-- change_table(:users)
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

SQLite3::SQLException: duplicate column name: email: ALTER TABLE "users" ADD "email" varchar(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL
```

This is the migration

```
class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    change_table(:users) do |t|
      t.database_authenticatable :null => false
      t.recoverable
      t.rememberable
      t.trackable

      # t.confirmable
      # t.lockable :lock_strategy => :failed_attempts, :unlock_strategy => :both
      # t.token_authenticatable


      t.timestamps
    end

    add_index :users, :email,                :unique => true
    add_index :users, :reset_password_token, :unique => true
    # add_index :users, :confirmation_token,   :unique => true
    # add_index :users, :unlock_token,         :unique => true
  end

  def self.down
    remove_column :users, :database_authenticatable
    remove_column :users, :recoverable
    remove_column :users, :rememberable
    remove_column :users, :trackable
    remove_index :users, :email
    remove_index :users, :reset_password_token
  end
end
```

In my schema.rb i already have this from Authlogic.

```
  create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    t.string    "username"
    t.string    "email"
    t.string    "crypted_password"
    t.string    "password_salt"
    t.string    "persistence_token"
```

I think it sees some kind of conflict that i'm not able to realize how to avoid with those devise helpers

Thank you!

Comment: Please mark jamuraa's answer as correct. Otherwise this question appears in the "unanswered questions list".

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The error that you're getting is because you are trying to recreate the `email` field which you already have.  The `email` field is created in the devise helper `t.database_authenticatable`.   You can use your old user table with the new system, but you don't need to include `t.database_authenticatable`, you just need to rename your old field names.  Looking in the [Documentation for Devise](http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/frames), you can see that `database_authenticatable` just creates three fields: email, encrypted_password and password_salt.  They are the same as the email, crypted_password, and password_salt that you already have in your authlogic user table, so you can use change_table like so:

```
def self.up
  change_table(:users) do |t|
    t.recoverable
    t.trackable
    # rememberable uses remember_token, but this field is different
    t.rename :remember_token_expires_at, :remember_created_at
    # these fields are named differently in devise
    t.rename :crypted_password, :encrypted_password
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you please reply or update the original question with your solution for others?

Answer (score 4):

Instead of changing the `create_table` to `change_table`, you can just add the following line just before `create_table`:

```
rename_table :users, :old_users_authlogic
```

Then, right after the `create_table`:

```
say_with_time 'Migrating users from Authlogic to Devise...' do
  execute "INSERT INTO users (id, email, ...) SELECT id, email FROM old_users_authlogic"
end
```

If you are using indexes with referential integrity, don't forget to update them to the new table, as the `rename_table` will make them point to `old_users_authlogic`.

Answer (score 0):

```
add_column(:users, :database_authenticatable, {:null=>false})
```

You are not providing information for how this field is to be setup. It needs to be a string I think so you want to pass that information.

```
add_column :users, :database_authenticatable, :string,  :null=>false
```

More information about the error you are getting:

```
undefined method `to_sym'
```

That error for migrations is really frustrating because it lacks content, but what it means is that you got your migration in the wrong order.

For example - if you add a boolean file to the use model:

```
 add_column :users, :user_is_a_jackass, :boolean, :default => false
```

That will migrate ok. But if you do it like this:

```
add_column :users, :user_is_a_jackass, :default => false
```

You will get the same error because you are not telling the migration what field type it should be.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What you said is true, however i realice that the original migration uses devise helpers and that's i think is why the migration was avoiding to define the type.

I realice i could change create_table to change_table and I just update the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by deleting Devise migration file but not removing it from Sublime. I then did a rails g migration remove_email_from_foo, thus removing email attribute. I then cancelled the Devise delete migration file which bought the migration file back in & ran a rake db:migrate. Devise attributes saved to model